# how to replace "Answer : 'A' " from "optionA = this is ans" column firebase firestore in anguler

Tags: angular, firebase

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AddquestionsComponent } from '../../forms/addquestions/addquestions.component'

import { ProjectService } from 'app/modules/admin/dashboards/project/project.service';
import { CrudService } from '../../../shared/crud.service'
import { getFirestore, addDoc, getDoc, getDocs, collection, doc, getDocFromCache } from "firebase/firestore"
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';




@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: './example.component copy.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})


export class ExampleComponent {



myArray: any[] = [];
displayedColumns: string[] = ['question','optionA','optionB','optionC','optionD','answer'];
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

constructor(
    private _projectService: ProjectService,
    private _matDialog: MatDialog,
    public crudApi: CrudService,
) {}

async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    // Get the data
    const db = getFirestore();
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "questions"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        this.myArray.push(doc.data());
        if(doc.data().answer == 'A'){
            console.log(doc.data().optionA);
        }else{
            console.log('Not option A');
        }

        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.myArray);
        // console.log(this.dataSource);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: For a better debug, change `console.log("Not option A");` to something like: `console.log(doc.data().answer);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.